# Convert Unicode to String with Ansible and Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I need help with converting a Unicode variable to a string in order for the below Ansible construct to work.

In this particular case, I want to use the `item.keys()` method in order to get the current `env` name (i.e. `uat`) but I get `[u'uat']` instead. I have been searching the Internet but could not find a way to convert `[u'uat']` to a simple `uat`.

`defaults/main.yml`:

```
blablabla:
  env:
    - uat:
        accounts:
          - david:
              email: david@example.com
          - anna:
              email: anna@example.com
    - develop:
        accounts:
          - john:
              email: john@example.com
```

`tasks/main.yml`:

```
- include_tasks: dosomething.yml
  with_items:
    - "{{ blablabla.env }}"
```

`tasks/dosomething.yml`:

```
- name: Get accounts
  set_fact:
    accounts: "{%- set tmp = [] -%}
                 {%- for account in item[item.keys()].accounts -%}  
                      {{ tmp.append(account) }}
                 {%- endfor -%}
               {{ tmp }}"
```

error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <failed value="True"/>
  <msg value="The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: dict object has no element [u'uat']

The error appears to have been in 'dosomething.yml': line 9, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


- name: Get accounts
  ^ here

exception type: &lt;class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'&gt;
exception: dict object has no element [u'uat']"/>
</root>
```

Alternatively, I would also welcome alternative approaches, as long the data structure (i.e. the `defaults/main.yml` file) remains unchanged.

Comment: The problem is not "unicode", it's that your variable is a list with a single element, rather than a string. This is because `keys()` returns a list of keys. But I can't work out why you are using that method there in any case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get `[u'uat']`

This is not a "Unicode string", this is a list ― pay attention to `[ ]`.

As `item.keys()` returns a list, but you want to use it as an index to `item[]`, you must select the element. So either use `first` filter or `[0]`:

```
- name: Get accounts
  set_fact:
    accounts: "{%- set tmp = [] -%}
                 {%- for account in item[item.keys()|first].accounts -%}  
                      {{ tmp.append(account) }}
                 {%- endfor -%}
               {{ tmp }}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick and great help! I don't know why I have not realised this myself while writing this question. At least this morning, while waking up, I had this thought but you had already answered.

Comment: This helped me a lot, thanks for the explanation @techraf